# Excel VBA open workbook with part of its name

Tags: vba, excel

I want to open, using VBA, a workbook from a certain path that includes a number, for example `2`. Any variation I tried is not working.

The name of the workbook is in Hebrew except for the number, so I want the VBA code to base the file name on the number to open the file.

I have 4 letters in hebrew before the number. In Hebrew we write from right to left.

Here is my code:

```
Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\RESULTS\" 2 & ".xlsx")
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: No, that wont work. The question states that there is some Hebrew text before the number 2, which should be ignored but is part of the file name

Comment: if the workbook has Hebrew wording in it and it includes the number you will need to search in the directory for the workbook you want? i will add answer with vba on how to search for files.

Comment: @DannyJames
not sure if you asking me or telling me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim sFound As String, fPath As String

fPath = "C:\RESULTS\"
sFound = Dir(fPath & "*2*.xlsx")   'get the first file in dir
If sFound <> "" Then
    Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(fPath & sFound)
End If
```

Comment: It says it can't find the file. I checked it and the file is in this path. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @RafaelOsipov - Firstly, is it going inside `IF` condition.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov - Debug and check the value of `sFound`.

Comment: @Mrig Why add another slash to fPath?

Comment: @RafaelOsipov - I've changed `sFound = Dir(fPath & "\" & "*2*.xlsx")` to `sFound = Dir(fPath & "*2*.xlsx")`. You may try this.

Comment: @Mrig - Same problem when setting WB1?

Comment: @MarcoVos - Oh man! end of the day, brain not working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim objFSO          As Object
    Dim objFolder       As Object
    Dim objFile         As Object
    Dim wbs             As Workbook

    Dim strExtension    As String
    Dim lngNumber       As String
    Dim lngAdditional   As Long
    Dim lngLenFile      As Long

    strExtension = ".xlsx"
    lngNumber = 20
    lngAdditional = 4

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Desktop\")
    lngLenFile = Len(strExtension) + Len(lngNumber) + lngAdditional

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If Left(objFile.Name, Len(lngNumber)) = lngNumber And _
                Right(objFile, Len(strExtension)) = strExtension And _
                Len(objFile.Name) = lngLenFile Then

            Debug.Print objFile.Name
            Set wbs = Workbooks.Open(objFile)

        End If
    Next objFile

End Sub
```

The idea of the code is to make it flexible, thus, `lngNumber` and `strExtension` are added. It checks always for the size, as well as for right and left. Thus `24Some.xlsx` would be different than `2Some.xlsx`.

`Debug.Print` is added to see the file that is opened.

`lngAdditional` is added, for the additional 4 chars.